# For infinite series convergence/divergence: Why doesnt meeting the conditions of the Divergence test imply the Cauchy Convergence Critierion

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Assume that the limit of the sequence is zero, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. So its not plainly obvious if the series $\sum a_n$ converges or diverges.

I have wondered for some time.  If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ then it must be the case that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+2}=0$ and so on.

Does it not make sense then that
$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n + a_{n+1} + a_{n+2}=0$

Cauchy's Convergence test basically says this, does it not?
$$\lim_{\substack{m\to\infty\\n\to\infty} }\sum_{k=m}^{m+n}a_k = 0$$

I realize that Cauchy's Convergence Criterion is a necessary and sufficient condition for convergence and divergence, while the Divergence test is just necessary for convergence.  That said, I am wondering *why*.  Why doesnt meeting the divergence test imply meeting Cauchy's convergence criterion?

Comment: Excellent question!

Comment: The difference is when you choose $\epsilon$ in your limits.

Cauchy says for a given $\epsilon$, there exists an $N$ such that the sum $|a_n + a_{n+1} + ... + a_{n+M}| < \epsilon$ for $n > N$ and all $M > 1$.

The thing you are saying is for a fixed $M$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ for which $|a_n + a_{n+1} + ... + a_{n+M}| < \epsilon$.  For different $M$, you will choose a different $\epsilon$ here

Comment: For a **fixed** number of terms, the limit is indeed $0$, but that is not enough for convergence.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is when you choose $\epsilon$ in your limits. Cauchy says for a given $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ such that the sum $|a_n+a_{n+1}+\cdots+a_{n+M}|<\epsilon$ for $n > N$ and all $M>1$. The thing you are saying is for a fixed $M$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ for which $|a_n+a_{n+1}+...+a_{n+M}|<\epsilon$. For different $M$, you will choose a different $\epsilon$ here.